# How to use onSuccess() when form submitted successfully?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

Actually I want, when submit my form successfully then show a message.

But now always show the message. Want, when the form submitted successfully. If not submitted successfully then don't show the message.

How do I know the form submitted successfully or not?
And how to do it?

***Here is my code:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#snoAlertBox").fadeIn();
  closeSnoAlertBox();
});

function closeSnoAlertBox() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $("#snoAlertBox").fadeOut(200000)
  }, 3000);
};
```

```css
#snoAlertBox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1400;
  top: 2%;
  right: 4%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding:20px;">
  <form action="">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="snoAlertBox" class="alert alert-success" data-alert="alert">Now Update your Search</div>
```

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: One option is post it to a controller or end-point and handle success or error f.e by redirecting the user to a thank-you page.

Comment: in your code you show, when the form is submitted, the page is reloaded, there is no success event any where

Comment: Hmm but can't do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What determines if the form has been submitted successfully? I don't see any validation or sending data to the server. Anyway, you can attach an event listener to your form, but first, you will need to add an id to it so it can be easily accessible via js.

Example:

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

```
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
// here you can show something on submit or do whatever you want
});
```